# setting first item as selected for hash type

Tags: angularjs

Using angularjs while creating a select element, I can set the first value as selected using

```
ng-init="item.state = stateArray[0]"
```

How to set the first item selected for key/value type array?

```
var States = { "AL": "Alabama", "AK": "Alaska", "AZ": "Arizona" }
```

html code:

```
<select  ng-model="item.state" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in States" class="form-control"></select>
```

I also tried

```
ng-init="item.state = Object.keys(States)[0]"
```

Comment: For the future, try to remember that `ng-init` should only be used for aliasing properties of `ng-repeat`. See the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit. That also makes an answer where the selected item is is set from the controller a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For ng-options**:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/17821/

**HTML**:

```
<select ng-init="o = getFirst();" ng-model="o" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in States" class="form-control"></select>
```

**JS:**

```
    $scope.States = {
    "AL": "Alabama",
        "AK": "Alaska",
        "AZ": "Arizona"
};
$scope.getFirst = function () {
    var v = Object.keys($scope.States)[0];
    return v;
};
```

**For ng-repeat**:

You can use `$first` for selecting the first option in case of ng-repeat.

```
ng-selected="$first?'selected':''"
```

Comment: For this I need to generate options using ng-repeat, right?

Comment: Yeah. You may try that option

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ng-init="item.state= stateArray['AL']"
```

Comment: Dont want some static code, Just want to select first, whatever the first item is.

Comment: would you please show your code or make a sample at plunkr because i think your code is right there is some other missings

Comment: and it will be easy if you do this operation in controller

Comment: if you dont mind i am sharing my another answer like i said using in controller

Comment: i got one more point you are using var keyword if you want to use this value in html you have assign it to $scope.stateArray = State;

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

In your controller,

```
$scope.States = { "AL": "Alabama", "AK": "Alaska", "AZ": "Arizona" };

var arrProp =   Object.getOwnPropertyNames($scope.States);

$scope.item = {};
$scope.item.state = arrProp[0];
```

And HTML as it is,

```
<select  ng-model="item.state" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in States" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select </option>
</select>
```